# Is it legal to audio or video tape professors while they are lecturing?

Tags: lecturer

Is it legal to audio or video tape professors while they are lecturing?

Why or why not?

Answer (score 3):

Requires permission.  In some locations, it is illegal to record anyone without their permission.  For what is legal in *your* location, consult a lawyer.